# Overriding nested values in polyfactory with pydantic models

Tags: python, pydantic, polyfactory

Is it possible to provide values for complex types generated by polyfactory?

I use pydantic for models and pydantic ModelFactory. I noticed that `build` method supports kwargs that can provide values for constructed model, but I didn't figure if it's possible to provide values for nested fields.

For example, if I have model A which is also the type for field a in model B, is ti possible to construct B via polyfactory and provide some values for field 'a'?

I tried to call build with

```
MyFactory.build(**{"a": {"nested_value": "b"}})
```

but it does not work.

Is it possible to override nested values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- just add another Factory for 'b'
- example code:

```
from pydantic_factories import ModelFactory
from datetime import date, datetime
from typing import List, Union, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel, UUID4
class B(BaseModel):
    k1: int
    k2: int

class Person(BaseModel):
    id: UUID4
    name: str
    hobbies: List[str]
    age: Union[float, int]
    birthday: Union[datetime, date]
    nested_model: B

class PersonFactory(ModelFactory):
    __model__ = Person

class KFactory(ModelFactory):
    __model__ = B

result = PersonFactory.build(**{"name" :"test","hobbies" : [1,2],"nested_model" : KFactory.build(k1=1,k2=2)})
print(result)
# same result
result = PersonFactory.build(**{"name" :"test","hobbies" : [1,2],"nested_model" : KFactory.build(**{"k1":1,"k2":2})})
print(result)
```

- result:

```
id=UUID('1ff7c9ed-223a-4f98-a95e-e3307426f54e') name='test' hobbies=['1', '2'] age=488202245.889748 birthday=datetime.date(2023, 3, 2) nested_model=B(k1=1, k2=2)
```